# Downcast from '[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?' to '[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]' only unwraps optionals

Tags: swift, collectionview

I'm trying to build a collection view with pagination (showing cells as previews) and found [this](http://blog.karmadust.com/centered-paging-with-preview-cells-on-uicollectionview/#comment-1156) tutorial. I'm getting the error from Xcode and guessing this must be due to an update to Xcode (since the tutorial seemed to have worked for a lot of people). Would love a hint on how to fix this:

> Downcast from '[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?' to
>   '[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]' only unwraps optionals; did you
>   mean to use '!'?

Comment: Can you post code?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/moopoints/THX-Collection-View-Demo/blob/master/SecondCollectionViewFlowLayout.swift) is the example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did something like this (`someOptionalAttributes` being of type `[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?`):

```
someOptionalAttributes as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
```

However, because `someOptionalAttributes` is just the optional version of `[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]`, you do not need a force downcast, you just need to unwrap it:

```
someOptionalAttributes!
```

Force downcasting is only necessary if casting to an entirely new type (usually subclass).

So, yes, you did mean to use `!` as said in the error. If you want to be safe, you could use a number of different optional unwrapping techniques.

Comment: Thanks! I tried modifying the line into "if let attributesForVisibleCells = self.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(cvBounds)!" but then I get this error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]'

Comment: @moopoints Ah, because when you use `if let`, you don't need force downcasting. Just change it to `if let attributesForVisibleCells = self.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(cvBounds)` — without the `!`.

Comment: Done! Thanks again